# How to get Control values from a web application that has been opened thru WPF WebBrowser Control(C#)

Tags: wpf

I have a problem.

I am calling an external application(web) through a WPF  WebBrowser Control. The

application is opening properly. Now in the web application, there are certain hyperelinks.

If a user click on that hyperlink, I should be able to trap it's value.

How to achieve the same using this WEB BROWSER.. I mean, in which event , what code I need to write to get it work

Using C#3.0, WPF and Dotnet framework 3.5

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
        private void _webBrowser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Uri.AbsolutePath))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            string actionName = e.Uri.LocalPath;
            MessageBox.Show(actionName);
        } 
    }
```

Regards,
Nanda